# How to remove default ligature definitions in semantic package?

Tags: ligatures

By default, when I load `\includepackage{semantic}`, it includes default ligatures such as `->` for `\to`. How can I disable this default behavior?

I only want to include ligatures that I have defined myself, so I can go back later if I want to and redefine them like `\mathlig{->}{\to}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just load the `ligature` mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ligature]{semantic}

\mathlig{*u}{U}

\begin{document}

$a->b$

$*u$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the standard `->` doesn't get replaced by `\to`, but you can define your own ligature.